# No module named Win32com.client error when using the pyttsx package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyttsx

Today, while surfing on *Quora*, I came across [answers](https://www.quora.com/What-amazing-things-can-Python-do) on amazing things that python can do. I tried to use the **pyttsx** *Text to Speech Convertor* and that gave me an `No module named Win32com.client` error.

There are many answers on this error but most of them weren't sufficient enough (Atleast for me) as the proposed solutions didn't matched the requirements.

For starters, I'm using Python2.7, and there are no DLLs in the `C:/Windows/System32` or any Scripts related to the keyword 'pywin32' in my `C:/Python27/Scripts` Folder. I need a concrete solution.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
>>> import pyttsx
>>> engine = pyttsx.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 39, in init
eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\engine.py", line 45, in __init__
self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\driver.py", line 64, in __init__
self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 19, in <module>
import win32com.client
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

**SOLUTION**: Install the package from [This Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/). Choose the 32/64 bit version depending on your Python installation type (32/64 bit).

Comment: you have to download and install it before it will work.

Comment: "pip install pyttsx" would normally do it, but you are on Windows, so no real idea how you use pip there

Comment: @PaulCollingwood `pip install pyttsx` It's already installed. Let me post the Traceback as well.

Comment: try pip install pywin32

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I'm sorry, It doesn't work. **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32**

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/

Comment: @PaulCollingwood There are 2 installers, the win32 one or the amd64 one?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood It WORKED!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. I installed pywin32 from [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) (download the build as per your preference). I downloaded for my python version (32 bit).

After installing I was able to import win32com.client

```
import win32com.client
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is from some time ago and the links are a little outdated, a simple run of

`pip install pywin32`

will install the correct version for your environment.  You should be able to run the `import win32com.client` without issue.  Be sure to restart your kernel to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I solved it with the below steps:

1.Open the cmd (run it in admin mode).

2.Enter the command:

```
conda install pywin32
```

or

```
pip install pywin32
```

I hope this works for you, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also going through the same issue and didn't find any satisfactory solution.
Then I just followed 2 steps and Voila :)

1. First of all, you have to download the **pywin32-217.win32-py2.7** from
   (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/).
2. Then you have to install it

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

run the code again and you will get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Installing relevant binary from [github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) helped me