# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

Tags: python, winapi, module

This is the error received:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joe Martin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\Joe Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

This error occurs when trying to import the win32com.client module.

Solutions Tried:

- Fresh wipe and install of Python 3.7
- `pip install pypiwin32`
- `pip install pywin32`
- Running the pywin32_postinstall.py

I cannot find any other solution for how to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.4 :ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257274/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

Comment: You probably have more than one Python interpreter installed.

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36112154/2825570)

Comment: @Jeril - I've explicitly stated I have tried that

Comment: @PeterWood - I Have Python's standard IDLE and PyCharm

Comment: @BaronMartin Kindly go through the entire solution, it is mentioned that you need to download and install `pywin32` from [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases). I guess you have not tried or mentioned about this in your problem.

Comment: Did you try to reboot after installing pywin32?

Answer (score 5):

This is usually because no `PythonPath` is appended after the package is installed.
Check the file--`pywin32.pth` under the folder--`\\PythonVersion\\Lib\\site-packages\\`.

The content in the file is like below:

```
# .pth file for the PyWin32 extensions
win32
win32\lib
Pythonwin
# Entries needed for a "portable" installations, where the post_install script
# isn't run, which would normally copy the pywin32 core DLL files to either
# the top of the python directory.
# We just stick the source of these DLLs directly on the PATH.
import os;os.environ["PATH"]+=(';'+os.path.join(sitedir,"pywin32_system32"))
```

Or create a `PYTHONPATH` environment variables, and append the `win32` and `win32/lib` path into it.

You could also add these two paths to Python in project **temporarily**：

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\\PythonVersion\\lib\\site-packages\\win32')
sys.path.append('\\PythonVersion\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib')
```

The addition of paths is only valid for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, the second option worked for me - but is there a way to avoid using this?

Answer (score 1):

@JohnJairo Your solution worked for me, too.

```
from win32 import win32api
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
from win32 import win32api

print("Width =", win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

None of the others possibilities worked for me. Python 3.9.6 (on Windows) IDLE 3.9.6 tk version 8.6.9

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by deleting the Python Environment and using the Global Default Environment. The correct Environment will have all the modules that you code is importing listed in the Python Environment window.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pCOI.png)