# ModuleNotFoundError for 'win32api' even pypiwin32 is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Windows10 and my python version 3.6.5
Its giving me error 'win32api'

import win32com.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
import win32com.client
File \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com__init__.py", line 5, in 
import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

pypiwin32 is already installed

Comment: Try restarting the python script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.4 :ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257274/python-3-4-importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238859/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-win32api

Answer (score 0):

It seems we need to restart the Python shell after installing the package pypiwin32. After restarting the shell, it worked.